# Pass values saved in cookie to where condition in Index Contet of custom Table Index (Smart Search) dynamically kentico 11

Tags: kentico

I have implemented smart search on custom table. The search has to be based on a value saved in cookie. Like if the userGroup in cookies is "One" then search should return the results from one only out of userGroups "One, Two and Three.
How to pass cookie value in where condition for custom table.

Answer (score 0):

Kentico supports Cookie macros .

To load values from the current user's browser cookies, use the following standard macro:

> {% Cookies["CookieName"] %}

For example:

The code of the currently selected language is: {% Cookies["CMSPreferredCulture"] %}

Reference - https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/macro-syntax